# What is the line seperator when reading a classpath resource that is a directory?

Tags: java

I was writing some java code that lists the files in a subdirectory on the Classpath as a stream.

```
InputStream is = YourClazz.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("subdirectory/")
```

This returns an `InputStream` which I then convert into a `String`.

```
String fileNames = "";
try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A")) {
    fileNames = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
}
```

I then used `System.getProperty("line.seperator")` to read the lines and be platform independent.

```
for (String fileName : fileNames.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"))) {
    // todo
}
```

But it failed on Windows as the delimiter in `fileNames` is `\n` and not `line.separator`. Is this because of the `Scanner`? I got this one-liner from [Read/convert an InputStream to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string/5445161#5445161)

**Update** based on answers below, I am using this code now, which works on Windows and Linux:

```
InputStream in = YourClazz.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("subdirectory/")
try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in)) {
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String fileName = scanner.nextLine();
        // todo
    }
}
```

Comment: Java resources don't have the concept of directory. Only of paths to resources. Your call to `getResourceAsStream` more than likely returns `null`. Right?

Comment: No. Like I said, it returns an InputStream wrapping a String that is a listing of filenames.

Comment: Yeah, but the `InputStream` is `null`. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't handle splitting lines manually. Let Scanner do it for you.

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is)) {
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        lines.add(scanner.nextLine());
        //or handle that line here instead of storing it in list
    }
}
```

Comment: I am on Java 7 sorry. Can you elaborate why I cannot know which line separator is used? The InputStream is created using: `YourClazz.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("subdirectory/")`. In other words is a listing of files in a directory - it's not a physical file sitting on my harddisk.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I though you ware reading text file, not directory.

Answer (score 1):

`getResourceAsStream()` is best understood as a short-hand for `getResource().openStream()`, in other words, what it provides when attempting to access a directory, is completely unspecified and left to the particular `URL` protocol handler. E.g. if the context is a Jar file, looking up directories usually fails. If the context is an `http` resource, attempting to get a directory may yield the contents of an `index.html`. Some protocols, e.g. `ftp`, may invariably use a `/` as separator, others may use the system’s file separator.

The only fail safe way is not to try to lookup a directory but a file resource, and then use an API which abstracts from the result and allows to resolve paths relative to the result and to list directories. Such an API exists since Java 7:

```
URI clURI = Object.class.getResource("Object.class").toURI();
if(!clURI.getScheme().equals("file")) try {
    FileSystems.getFileSystem(clURI);
} catch(FileSystemNotFoundException ex) {
    FileSystems.newFileSystem(clURI, Collections.<String,Object>emptyMap());
}
for(Path p: Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(clURI).getParent())) {
  System.out.println(p.toUri());
}
```

This will list all (virtual) files located in the same package as `java.lang.Object`, usually a `jar` resource for which `URL` based lookups for a directory fail. It works similarly for other `class` location. Note that it doesn’t rely on a particular separator at all.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use:

```
 Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
 String[] files = fileName.split(path.getFileSystem().getSeparator());
```

Edit: My bad I got this question wrongly. This will get file separator not line separator as you needed.

Comment: Doesn't work. For instance on the `MacOSXFileSystem` the value of `getSeparator()` is `/` but an example value of `fileNames` above looks like `ns_test1.json\nns_test2.json\n`